# script to load/unload psmouse module by user (no root)

Tags: shell-script, mouse, non-root-user, modprobe

I want to write a shell script that can be executed by a user w/o root permissions that will simply execute
`modprobe -r psmouse` or `modprobe psmouse`.
Is this even possible?
I've got this module:

```
$ ls -l /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 219670 Feb 12 17:06 /lib/modules/4.4.0-116-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
```

Is it fine to just change the permissions of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tweak your sudo security policy, making up a rule in `/etc/sudoers.d` that allows:

- a defined set of users (possibly only one user or a group as needed),
- to ONLY execute `modprobe` and `rmmod`,
- ONLY on cmd argument `psmouse`,
- WITH or WITHOUT sudo password.

This is exactly what '/etc/sudoers.d' is generally used for. So here goes... (assuming single host configuration and remembering that files located in `/etc/sudoers.d` are parsed by `sudo` in sorted lexical order.)

- make sure that `/etc/sudoers` includes the line `#include /etc/sudoers.d`
- I usually work with a personal default file `/etc/sudoers.d/00_aliases` where I define user, cmd, host and group aliases to taste. This way not only do I drastically reduce my use of `sudo visudo` to tweak `/etc/sudoers`, which contains default base-system settings, but my other files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` get to use aliases parsed first by `sudo` in `/etc/sudoers.d/00_aliases`.
- drop a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`, named for example 20_psmouse

If you don't plan on using drop-in sudoers.d files extensively, you may want to ***not*** create `/etc/sudoers.d/00_aliases` and instead include your ad-hoc aliases directly in your drop-in files as shown below.

```
User_Alias  MOUSE_TWKR = user1[, user2[, user3[, ...]]]
Cmnd_Alias  MOUSE_MOD_TWK = /usr/bin/modprobe, /usr/bin/rmmod
MOUSE_TWKR  your-host = NOPASSWD: MOUSE_MOD_TWK psmouse
```

The truth is in the pudding, so you will need to:
   1) consult `man sudoers` (on Archlinux, examples start at line 1911 out of 2038 lines !!) and 
   2) experiment a little. 
For instance if the rule above is too permissive and you want to restrict the use of any options along with cmds `modprobe` and `rmmod` in the context you are administering, substitute the file entry with:

```
 MOUSE_TWKR  your-host = NOPASSWD: MOUSE_MOD_TWK [!-] psmouse
```

... and with mandatory password entry:

```
 MOUSE_TWKR  your-host = MOUSE_MOD_TWK [!-] psmouse
```

*(*) replace "your-host" with your hostname, or with `ALL` to allow all hosts, the which reduces just to yr host if yr system is a stand-alone box and/or you're not dealing with remote admin on a subnet for instance...*

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permissions on the `psmouse.ko` file won't do much besides make it possible for someone to alter the file (which would be a bad thing!) You could allow them to run `modprobe` and `rmmod`, but that would be dangerous too, because they could then theoretically load and unload any kernel module that is installed on your system!

What you want is to make a small helper script and allow the allowed users to run that as `root`:

1. Make the scripts:

   **/usr/local/bin/load_mouse.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /sbin/modprobe psmouse
   ```

   **/usr/local/bin/unload_mouse.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /sbin/rmmod psmouse
   ```

   The scripts should be in a publicly-accessible directory (I like `/usr/local/bin`, but that's personal preference), with the owner `root:root` and permissions `755`. `root` ownership isn't required, but it makes it harder for people to change: remember, these scripts need to run as the superuser, so you want them to be secure!
2. Allow users to run them

   Using `visudo` (or adding a drop-in file into `/etc/sudoers.d`), add the following:

   ```
   username ALL=(root) /usr/local/bin/load_mouse.sh,/usr/local/bin/unload_mouse.sh
   ```

   Replace `username` with the appropriate username, or `%groupname` if you want the members of a group to be able to run this.

   Users should now be able to run the script using `sudo /usr/local/bin/load_mouse.sh` (or `unload_mouse`). If `/usr/local/bin` is in their `PATH`, then `sudo load_mouse.sh` would work too.
3. (optional) Wrap the `sudo` call

   Lastly, you can wrap the `sudo` in another script so that it's easier to type/execute:

   **/usr/local/bin/mouse_on**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sudo /usr/local/bin/load_mouse.sh
   ```

   **/usr/local/bin/mouse_off**

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sudo /usr/local/bin/unload_mouse.sh
   ```

   These don't have to have any special rights, but I like to keep them owned by `root:root` with permissions of `755`. Now users can simply type `mouse_on` and `mouse_off` (as long as you allowed them to run the scripts!)

Comment: I think a better/simpler solution would be: just define a rule in /etc/sudoers.d that allows a defined set of users (possibly only one user as you noted) to ONLY execute `modprobe`and `rmmod`, ONLY on cmd argument `psmouse`, while making it possible WITHOUT sudo password. After all this is exactly what `sudoers.d` is generally used for.  No wrapper, no sudo password, no fiddling with `sudo chown`...

Comment: @Cbhihe Yes, exactly, your suggestion is what I did and it works like a charm! Thanks, convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it!